# kaptGenerateStubs task throws java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stack-overflow, kapt

We have a Java / Kotlin project that builds on Jenkins job, sometimes, it just throws `java.lang.StackOverflowError` and after restarting job it disappears.
Do any of you encounter this before?

```
14:00:01 > Task :app:mergeClientFlavorDebugAssets
14:00:01 > Task :app:processClientFlavorDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
14:00:01 > Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesClientFlavorDebug
14:00:02 > Task :app:mergeClientFlavorDebugResources
14:00:03 > Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesClientFlavorDebug
14:00:09 > Task :app:processClientFlavorDebugResources
14:00:26
14:00:26 > Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsClientFlavorDebugKotlin
14:00:26 e: java.lang.StackOverflowError
14:00:27    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.parsing.KotlinExpressionParsing.parsePrefixExpression(KotlinExpressionParsing.java:343)
14:00:27    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.parsing.KotlinExpressionParsing.access$200(KotlinExpressionParsing.java:43)
14:00:27    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.parsing.KotlinExpressionParsing$Precedence$2.parseHigherPrecedence(KotlinExpressionParsing.java:167)
...
```

Comment: Sometimes these weird errors are related to running out of memory or it could be some weird caching issue. Maybe also try to update all related build tools?

Comment: I will update all of them, and try not to face this error again